# Getting email address in web scraping through rvest

Tags: r, screen-scraping

Hi I am trying to get little information about this webpage through web scraping in R language using the package rvest. I am getting name and everything but I am unable to get email id i.e. *info@brewhemia.co.uk*. If I see in the *read_html* as text, I don't see email id in html parsed text. Can anybody please help? I am new to web scraping. But I know R Language.

```
link <- 'https://food.list.co.uk/place/22191-brewhemia-edinburgh/'
page <- read_html(link)
name_html <- html_nodes(page,'.placeHeading')
business_adr <- html_text(adr_html)
tel_html <- html_nodes(page,'.value')
business_tel <- html_text(tel_html)
```

The email id is in 'a' html tag but I am not able to extract it. [image: This is the page source code]

Comment: Because it's dynamically created by js. Check page source.

Comment: Would love to hear if it helped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a javascript engine here to process the js code. Luckily, R has got `V8`.

Modify your code after installing `V8` package:

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)

link <- 'https://food.list.co.uk/place/22191-brewhemia-edinburgh/'
page <- read_html(link)
name_html <- html_nodes(page,'.placeHeading')
business_adr <- html_text(adr_html)
tel_html <- html_nodes(page,'.value')
business_tel <- html_text(tel_html)

emailjs <- page %>% html_nodes('li') %>% html_nodes('script') %>% html_text()
ct <- v8()

read_html(ct$eval(gsub('document.write','',emailjs))) %>% html_text()
```

Output:

```
> read_html(ct$eval(gsub('document.write','',emailjs))) %>% html_text()
[1] "info@brewhemia.co.uk"
```

Comment: It is giving error about ct.

Error in read_html(ct$eval(gsub("document.write", "", emailjs))) : 
  object 'ct' not found

Comment: My bad, missed it. Please check the updated answer with ```ct <- v8()```

Comment: I have got an error to run as below. 
Error in xml2::xml_text(x, trim = trim) : object 'adr_html' not found